# Get all conversations by user and display in inbox view in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm creating a basic user to user messaging for my site to allow registered users to private message each other. Now, I'm trying to display all the conversations that I (current logged in user) have with other users. And display them in a regular inbox view with other user's name and photo along with 1 most recent message in each conversation.

I have 3 tables.

**threads**

```
id
deleted_at
```

**participants**

```
id
thread_id
user_id
blocked
```

**messages**

```
id
thread_id
user_id
body
```

I've managed to make it work in single conversation view between me (current user) and another user. But I'm having trouble displaying all conversations I have with other users in inbox view.

What's the most efficient way to retrieve all of my conversations and display it in inbox view along with one latest message of each conversation either my own message or other user's message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is untested code that might put you in the right direction

**Relationships**

Define the relationships in your models. Assuming you have three models: Thread, Participant, and Message, and a User model, define the relationships like this:

```php
// User.php
public function threads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Thread::class, 'participants', 'user_id', 'thread_id');
}

// Thread.php
public function participants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Participant::class);
}

public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}

// Message.php
public function thread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class);
}
```

Read more about relationships here [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

**Retrieve threads**

Retrieve the threads and their most recent messages for the current logged-in user:

```php
$userId = auth()->id();

$threads = Thread::whereHas('participants', function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})
->with(['messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->latest()->first();
}])
->get();
```

This query finds all threads in which the current user is a participant and eager loads the most recent message for each thread.

**Display results**

```
@foreach ($threads as $thread)
    @foreach ($thread->participants as $participant)
        @if ($participant->user_id !== $userId)
            <div>
                <span>{{ $participant->user->name }}</span>
                <p>{{ $thread->messages->first()->body }}</p>
            </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Can you please provide an SQL builder version for your query? I very much appreciated your effort and time in answering my question.

Comment: What do you mean SQL builder version ??

Comment: Never mind. I'm using your code. Amazing! It worked out of the box. Thank you!